# AWS based IoT backend app performance improvement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, iot, database-performance

Looking for advice about improving the performance of the IoT backend app running on AWS.
Current IoT data flow: ~10M sensors samples a day with peaks every ~4h. Each sample is a JSON file of ~10-100KB.

The goal:

1. Store raw data as it arrives from IoT devices (currently stored in S3).
2. Raw data should pass data enrichment processing and enriched data (samples) to be stored in separate storage (currently stored in RDS PostgreSQL + DMS task is running to migrate all data to Redshift).
3. Be able to query sample data for real-time analytics running ~10 times a day (currently query RDS PostgreSQL).
4. Be able to query sample data for offline analytics by data engineers (currently, query Redshift data migrated by DMS from RDS PostgreSQL).
5. Access to data is done by Lambdas.

Main problem: RDS PostgreSQL performance to write/read sample data particularly in peaks when real-time analytics tasks are running.

Secondary problem: improve IoT data processing pipeline to support future scalability and ability to analyze data on-the-fly.

Comment: Have you looked into the kinesis services on aws? You could setup a kinesis stream for real-time analytics and kinesis firehose to buffer the data and write it to Redshift every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is the direction I am thinking about. Will try it.